# Resize MDI parent workarea based from child forms size

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I'm trying to make my parent form MDI workarea to adjust from the child form size..

I have this code

```
Child.MdiParent = Me
Child.Show()
Me.Size = New Size(Child.Width, Child.Height)
```

but it resize the whole parent form. showing some scrollbars in the MDI workarea.

`Parent size`: `H:400`, `W: 800`

Parent mdisize. `H:350`, `W:800` .. theres 50 because i have custom title bar. docked at top.

`Child size`: `H:200`, `W: 400`

Now i want the `parent size` to `H:250`, `W:400`... but it shows scrollbars means that its not perfectly fitted. need help guys...

Comment: The fat Aero borders are the problem.  Making the window bigger than it says it is.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else may have a better suggestion, but the way I've always done this is by calculating the difference between the parent form's client size and it's actual size:

```
Dim nonClientWidth As Integer = Me.Size.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width
Dim nonClientHeight As Integer = Me.Size.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height
Me.Size = New Size(Child.Width + nonClientWidth, Child.Height + nonClientHeight)
```